# How to Filter Relationships with Null 'Type' and Polymorphic Many-to-Many in Filament's ComponentRelationManager

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, many-to-many

I have a challenging question for today.

I have these two relationships.

In Filament's ComponentRelationManager, I have the "attach" action.

However, before becoming relationships, the sub-products I want to connect have a "type" set to null.

How can I make sure that when searching for products to associate, it finds those with a null "type"? I tried using the `recordSelectOptionsQuery` like this:

```php
recordSelectOptionsQuery(fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('product_morph.type', null))
```

But it treats it as an "AND" condition instead of replacing the query with the one where "type" is equal to "component." Are there better ways to achieve this?

Also orWhere doesn't work to attach the relation-

PS: The relationship is both polymorphic many-to-many with other models and self-referential, which is why I need to use "type" to differentiate the type of relationship with the same model.

```php
public function components(): MorphToMany
{
    $pivot_class = ProductMorph::class;
    $pivot = app($pivot_class);
    $pivot_table = $pivot->getTable();
    $pivot_fields = $pivot->getFillable();

    return $this->morphToMany(Product::class, 'model', $pivot_table)
        ->using($pivot_class)
        ->withPivot($pivot_fields)
        ->withTimestamps() 
        ->wherePivot('type', 'component');
}

public function variations(): MorphToMany
{
    $pivot_class = ProductMorph::class;
    $pivot = app($pivot_class);
    $pivot_table = $pivot->getTable();
    $pivot_fields = $pivot->getFillable();

    return $this->morphToMany(Product::class, 'model', $pivot_table)
        ->using($pivot_class)
        ->withPivot($pivot_fields)
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->wherePivot('type', 'variation');
}
```

Comment: whereNull('column') is the right way.

On the other hand I see only disadvantages for this polymorphic type of relationships. Why merge 2 relations into one polymorphic...

Comment: Because it is always a subproduct, but with a different type or scope

Comment: And storing the class/model name in db seems a good ideea? What if you rename the class? Thank you for your reply. I will delete my account. So that is why I will stop answering.

Comment: the classes are not saved in the db because I use morph_maps